# Time Weighted Decay

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, recreational-mathematics, finance, weighted-least-squares

I've been tasked to calculate/forecast the weighted exposure of a financial product.
I work with bunker prices and we have access to bunker future prices everyday. They look similar to this in an excel sheet:

```
Prices of futures on 1st Feb 2024

Feb 2024 - $120
Mar 2024 - $110
Apr 2024 - $108
...
Jan 2027 - $70
```

I have access to similar prices on 2nd Feb, 3rd Feb, ... to current date. Each file has the same format prices.

I'm trying to understand how I can use these prices to come up with some sort of weighted price change indication.

For example: [Price on 1st Feb 2024](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9zM2.jpg)
This image shows the prices plotted out on a line graph. Price of `June 2024` = `$100` and price of `Jan 2027` = `$70`.

Similarly, on [Price on 31st Feb 2024](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjgXJ.jpg), the price of `June 2024` = `$90` and price of `Jan 2027` = `$69`.

This indicates that there is a BIGGER CHANGE when the future dates are closer to current day and smaller when further. i.e. A dollar change in today's prices will only result in a $0.10 change in a much further future price. Nearer changes can be seen to have a 100% effect but further changes only a fraction of it.

[See this image to look at the price comparisons on earlier vs later dates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QY3N9.jpg)

What is this concept exactly and how can I use the different prices obtained everyday to come up with something like a `weight` for each month similar to this:

```
Feb 2024 - 100%
Mar 2024 - 99.92%
Apr 2024 - 99.75%
...
Jan 2027 - 80%
Feb 2027 - 79.95%
...
```

Eventually I want to use the weighted percentages from 2024 to 2028 to FORECAST up to 2034.

WHAT IS THIS CONCEPT? I tried my best to describe it to chatgpt/google and I see 'Time Weighted Decay' but Im not sure. Please send help.